# SAME audio as output in 8 Bands Sound Equalizer with FIR filter and GUI in python

Tags: python, user-interface, audio, filter

Having SAME audio as output in 8 Bands Sound Equalizer with FIR filter and GUI in python

I tried to figure the filters functions, they should be correct, gain values are moved correctly to specified functions. But still, input = output no matter what gain you put..?

Actually, this code should let you choose the file and save it for equalizing, but the saved is same as input

```
# 8 BANDS GUI FIR FILTER
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
import numpy as np
import os
import wave
from scipy.io.wavfile import write
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
from scipy import signal
from scipy.signal import butter, lfilter
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.io import wavfile
import pygame
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg,
NavigationToolbar2Tk)
# Implement the default Matplotlib key bindings.
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from scipy import signal
band_centers = [30, 115.5, 240.5, 455.5, 801, 2000, 4500, 9000] # For GUI to show each band center when controlled in GUI
db1 = db2 = db3 = db4 = db5 = db6 = db7 = db8 = 0 # Gains are set to zero in default
n=0 # Global variable to prevent repeating the plot if user clicks plotting many times
z=0 # Global variable to lower the number of calculations (so final value of the scroll is only considered)
root = tk.Tk() # GUI MAIN WINDOW
root.configure(bg="white") # Setting GUI background color
root.title("Audio Processing") # Setting GUI Title
root.geometry("2000x2000") # Setting GUI size

# Global variables
selected_file = None # The file your are going to select is going to be shared between functions, set as global
stop_flag = False

def bandpass_filter(data, lowcut, highcut, fs):
    nyquist_freq = 0.5 * fs
    cutoff_normalized_low = lowcut / nyquist_freq
    cutoff_normalized_high = highcut / nyquist_freq
    # Designing the bandpass filter using the Hamming window method
    num_taps = int(np.ceil(fs / (highcut - lowcut)))
    if num_taps % 2 == 0:  # To ensure odd number of taps
        num_taps += 1
    taps = signal.firwin(num_taps, [cutoff_normalized_low, cutoff_normalized_high], window='hamming', pass_zero=False)

    # Apply the filter to the input signal
    filtered_signal = signal.lfilter(taps, 2, data)

    return filtered_signal
def highpass_filter(data, freqcut, fs):
    # Designing the highpass filter using the Kaiser window method
    nyquist_freq = 0.5 * fs
    cutoff_normalized = freqcut / nyquist_freq
    num_taps = int(np.ceil(fs / freqcut))
    if num_taps % 2 == 0:  # Ensure odd number of taps
        num_taps += 1
    taps = signal.firwin(num_taps, cutoff_normalized, window='hamming', pass_zero=False)

    # Apply the filter to the input signal
    filtered_signal = signal.lfilter(taps, 2, data)

    return filtered_signal
def lowpass_filter(data, freqcut, fs):
    nyquist_freq = 0.5 * fs
    cutoff_normalized = freqcut / nyquist_freq
    # Design the lowpass filter using the rectangular window method
    num_taps = int(np.ceil(fs / freqcut))
    if num_taps % 2 == 0:  # Ensure odd number of taps
        num_taps += 1
    taps = signal.firwin(num_taps, cutoff_normalized, window='rectangular')

    # Apply the filter to the input signal
    filtered_signal = signal.lfilter(taps, 2, data)

    return filtered_signal
def select_file(): # Function dedicated for selecting the file
    global selected_file
    selected_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[('WAV Files', '*.wav')]) # Allowing to select a WAV file
    file_label.config(text="Selected File: " + selected_file)  # Update the label to show the user what he selected in GUI window
    return selected_file # Pass the file 
def _quit():
    root.quit()     # stops mainloop
    root.destroy()  # this is necessary on Windows to prevent lagging
                    # Fatal Python Error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate
def listen(): # A function to listen to main sound
    # Initialize pygame
    pygame.init()
    # Set up parameters
    global selected_file  # Location of the WAV file
    volume = 1  # volume level (0.0 to 1.0)
    # Load the audio file
    pygame.mixer.music.load(selected_file)
    # Set the volume
    pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(volume)
    # Play the audio file
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    # Wait for the audio to finish playing
    while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
        pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)
    # Clean up
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    pygame.quit()
    rate, data = wav.read(selected_file)
    duration = len(data) / rate
    print(f"Audio duration: {duration} seconds")
    return selected_file
def plotting_original(): # A function to plot original time and frequency plots
    global n
    if n==0: # if no plots before n=0, otherwise do not plot again
        # Load audio file
        global selected_file
        fs, audio =  wavfile.read(selected_file)
        # Compute the length of the audio signal in seconds
        audio_len = len(audio) / fs

        # Generate time array
        time = np.linspace(0, audio_len, len(audio))

        # Compute the FFT of the audio signal
        freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(len(audio)) * fs
        fft = np.fft.fft(audio)
        fig = Figure(figsize = (6, 3), dpi = 80)
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,master = root)
        canvas.draw()
        # placing the canvas on the SAME Tkinter window
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
        # placing the toolbar on the Tkinter window
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
        # Plot the audio signal in the time domain
        plot1 = fig.add_subplot(311)
        plot1_widget = canvas.get_tk_widget()
        plot1.set_title("Original Sound Time Domain Representation")
        plot1_widget.place(x=500,y=0)
        # plotting the graph
        plot1.plot(time,audio)
        plot2 = fig.add_subplot(313)
        plot2.set_title("Original Sound Frequency Domain Representation")
        plot2.plot(freqs[:len(audio)//2], np.abs(fft[:len(audio)//2]))
        n=1 # Plot is saved, no need to plot it again
    else:
        exit
def plotting_equalized():# A function to plot equalized time and frequency plots
    # Load audio file
    global file_path
    fs, audio =  wavfile.read(file_path)
    # Compute the length of the audio signal in seconds
    audio_len = len(audio) / fs

    # Generate time array
    time = np.linspace(0, audio_len, len(audio))

    # Compute the FFT of the audio signal
    freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(len(audio)) * fs
    fft = np.fft.fft(audio)
    fig = Figure(figsize = (6, 3), dpi = 80)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,master = root)
    canvas.draw()
    # placing the canvas on the SAME Tkinter window
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
    # placing the toolbar on the Tkinter window
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
    # Plot the audio signal in the time domain
    plot1_widget = canvas.get_tk_widget()
    plot1 = fig.add_subplot(311)
    plot1_widget = canvas.get_tk_widget()
    plot1.set_title("Equalized Sound Time Domain Representation")
    plot1_widget.place(x=500, y=300)
    # plotting the graph
    plot1.plot(time,audio,color='red')
    plot2 = fig.add_subplot(313)
    plot2.set_title("Equalized Sound Frequency Domain Representation")
    plot2.plot(freqs[:len(audio)//2], np.abs(fft[:len(audio)//2]), color='purple')
def db1_f(db11): # This function is dedicated for band 1, taking the gain db11 from the GUI
    global db1
    db1 = float(db11)
    if z == 1: # when z=1, it means the final gain value is being selected by saving button in GUI
        global selected_file
        fs, audio =  wav.read(selected_file)
        band1 = lowpass_filter(audio,60, fs)* 10**(db1/20) # default db's = 0, as a result 10**(db1/20) = 1
        return band1
def db2_f(db22):# This function is dedicated for band 2, taking the gain db2 from the GUI
    global db2
    db2 = float(db22)
    if z == 1:
        global selected_file
        fs, audio =  wav.read(selected_file)
        band2 = bandpass_filter(audio, 61, 170, fs)*10**(db2/20)
        return band2
def db3_f(db33):# This function is dedicated for band 3, taking the gain db33 from the GUI
    global db3
    db3 = float(db33)
    global selected_file
    if z == 1:
        fs, audio =  wav.read(selected_file)
        band3 = bandpass_filter(audio, 171, 310, fs)*10**(db3/20)
        return band3
def db4_f(db44):# This function is dedicated for band 4, taking the gain db44 from the GUI
    global db4
    db4 = float(db44)
    if z == 1:
        global selected_file
        fs, audio =  wav.read(selected_file)
        band4 = bandpass_filter(audio, 311, 600, fs)* 10**(db4/20)
        return band4
def db5_f(db55):# This function is dedicated for band 5, taking the gain db55 from the GUI
    global db5
    db5 = float(db55)
    global selected_file
    if z == 1:
        fs, audio =  wav.read(selected_file)
        band5 = bandpass_filter(audio, 601, 1000, fs)* 10**(db5/20)
        return band5
def db6_f(db66):# This function is dedicated for band 6, taking the gain db66 from the GUI
    global db6
    db6 = float(db66)
    global selected_file
    if z == 1:
        fs, audio =  wav.read(selected_file)
        band6 = bandpass_filter(audio, 1000.1, 3000, fs)* 10**(db6/20)
        return band6
def db7_f(db77):# This function is dedicated for band 7, taking the gain db77 from the GUI
    global db7
    db7 = float(db77)
    global selected_file
    if z == 1:
        fs, audio =  wav.read(selected_file)
        band7 = bandpass_filter(audio, 3000.1, 6000, fs)* 10**(db7/20)
        return band7
def db8_f(db88):# This function is dedicated for band 8, taking the gain db88 from the GUI
    global db8
    db8 = float(db88)
    global selected_file
    if z == 1:
        fs, audio =  wav.read(selected_file)
        band8 = highpass_filter(audio, 6000.1, fs)* 10**(db8/20)
        return band8
def listen2():# A function to listen to equlaized sound
    # Initialize pygame
    pygame.init()
    # Set up parameters
    global file_path  # Location of the WAV file
    volume = 1  # volume level (0.0 to 1.0)
    # Load the audio file
    pygame.mixer.music.load(file_path)
    # Set the volume
    pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(volume)
    # Play the audio file
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    # Wait for the audio to finish playing
    while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
        pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)
    # Clean up
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    pygame.quit()
    rate, data = wav.read(file_path)
    duration = len(data) / rate
    print(f"Audio duration: {duration} seconds")
def saveit(): # A function to save final gain values in GUI, select the file location, and save it as WAV
    fs, audio =  wav.read(selected_file)
    global db1, db2, db3, db4, db5, db6, db7, db8
    global z
    z=1 # z = 1 because user clicks save when he stops varying the gain
    band1 = db1_f(db1)
    band2 = db2_f(db2)
    band3 = db3_f(db3)
    band4 = db4_f(db4)
    band5 = db5_f(db5)
    band6 = db6_f(db6)
    band7 = db7_f(db7)
    band8 = db8_f(db8)
    signal = band1 + band2 + band3 + band4 + band5 + band6 + band7 + band8
    global file_path
    file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".wav")
    print(file_path)
    # Check if the user selected a file
    if file_path:
        max_value = np.max(np.abs(signal))
        normalized_data = signal / max_value * 32767  # Scale to 16-bit range

        # Convert to 16-bit integers
        normalized_data = normalized_data.astype(np.int16)

        # Save the filtered WAV file
        wav.write(file_path, fs, normalized_data)
def create_gui():
    
    # File selection button
    select_button = tk.Button(root, text="Select WAV File", command=select_file,width=40 )
    select_button.pack(pady=10)
    select_button.place(x=0,y=0) 
    # Selected file label
    global file_label
    file_label = tk.Label(root, text="", bg="white", fg="red", font=("Arial", 8))
    file_label.pack()
    file_label.place(x=0,y=20) 
    # Listen buttons
    listen_button = tk.Button(root, text="Listen to original sound file", command=listen, bg="white", fg="blue",width=40)
    listen_button.pack(pady=5)
    listen_button.place(x=0,y=40) 
    listen2_button = tk.Button(root, text="Listen to equlaized sound", command=listen2, bg="white", fg="purple",width=40)
    listen2_button.pack(pady=5)
    listen2_button.place(x=0,y=120) 
    # Plotting buttons
    plot_button = tk.Button(root, text="Plot original sound file in time and frequency", command=plotting_original, bg="white", fg="blue",width=40)
    plot_button.pack(pady=5)
    plot_button.place(x=0,y=80) 
    plot_button2 = tk.Button(root, text="Plot equalized sound file in time and frequency", command=plotting_equalized, bg="white", fg="purple",width=40)
    plot_button2.pack(pady=5)
    plot_button2.place(x=0,y=160) 
    # Sliders for gain
    sliders = []
    slider_1 = tk.Scale(root, from_=-12, to=12, resolution=0.1, orient='horizontal', bg="white",length=200, label='Band {} ({} Hz)'.format(0+1, band_centers[0]), command = db1_f, font=("Arial", 10))
    slider_1.set(0)
    slider_1.pack()
    slider_1.place(x=1060,y=0)
    sliders.append(slider_1)
    slider_2 = tk.Scale(root, from_=-12, to=12, resolution=0.1, orient='horizontal',bg="white", length=200, label='Band {} ({} Hz)'.format(0+2, band_centers[1]), command = db2_f, font=("Arial", 10))
    slider_2.set(0)
    slider_2.pack()
    slider_2.place(x=1060,y=60)
    sliders.append(slider_2)
    slider_3 = tk.Scale(root, from_=-12, to=12, resolution=0.1, orient='horizontal',bg="white", length=200, label='Band {} ({} Hz)'.format(0+3, band_centers[2]), command = db3_f, font=("Arial", 10))
    slider_3.set(0)
    slider_3.pack()
    slider_3.place(x=1060,y=120)
    sliders.append(slider_3)
    slider_4 = tk.Scale(root, from_=-12, to=12, resolution=0.1, orient='horizontal',bg="white", length=200, label='Band {} ({} Hz)'.format(0+4, band_centers[3]), command = db4_f, font=("Arial", 10))
    slider_4.set(0)
    slider_4.pack()
    slider_4.place(x=1060,y=180)
    sliders.append(slider_4)
    slider_5 = tk.Scale(root, from_=-12, to=12, resolution=0.1, orient='horizontal',bg="white", length=200, label='Band {} ({} Hz)'.format(0+5, band_centers[4]), command = db5_f, font=("Arial", 10))
    slider_5.set(0)
    slider_5.pack()
    slider_5.place(x=1060,y=240)
    sliders.append(slider_5)
    slider_6 = tk.Scale(root, from_=-12, to=12, resolution=0.1, orient='horizontal',bg="white", length=200, label='Band {} ({} Hz)'.format(0+6, band_centers[5]), command = db6_f, font=("Arial", 10))
    slider_6.set(0)
    slider_6.pack()
    slider_6.place(x=1060,y=300)
    sliders.append(slider_6)
    slider_7 = tk.Scale(root, from_=-12, to=12, resolution=0.1, orient='horizontal',bg="white", length=200, label='Band {} ({} Hz)'.format(0+7, band_centers[6]), command = db7_f, font=("Arial", 10))
    slider_7.set(0)
    slider_7.pack()
    slider_7.place(x=1060,y=360)
    sliders.append(slider_7)
    slider_8 = tk.Scale(root, from_=-12, to=12, resolution=0.1, orient='horizontal',bg="white", length=200, label='Band {} ({} Hz)'.format(0+8, band_centers[7]), command = db8_f, font=("Arial", 10))
    slider_8.set(0)
    slider_8.pack()
    slider_8.place(x=1060,y=420)
    sliders.append(slider_8)
    save_button = tk.Button(master=root, text="Save File & Equalization", command=saveit, bg="white", fg="Green", font=("Arial", 10), width =20)
    save_button.pack(pady=5)
    save_button.place(x=1080,y=500) 
    quit_button = tk.Button(master=root, text="Quit", command=_quit, bg="white", fg="red", font=("Arial", 14), width =15)
    quit_button.pack(pady=5)
    quit_button.place(x=650,y=550) 
    root.mainloop()


# Create the GUI
create_gui()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).